# How is a Magus' Spellstrike and Spell Combat affected by Silence?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature, magus

This question was asked in another post that it was later edited out of. I'd like to re-post the RAW answer for future reference. The context was high-level melee combat where the the PC was going to be fighting a Magus. He had attained an item providing temporary Silence Aura. He wanted to know what the Magus' abilities would be within the aura (no save because the character accepted the silence onto himself).

Comment: Do you want an answer to this or do you plan to answer it yourself?

Comment: @Nickmagus By all means add an answer if you have one! For context, the reason this started with a self-answer is explained by [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37582/how-can-i-make-a-high-level-magus-fail-a-will-save#comment175763_37582) and [this](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37582/how-can-i-make-a-high-level-magus-fail-a-will-save#comment175766_78376).

Comment: There is a wait-time to 'accept' my own answer. I'll approve it when the system allows me. The answer provided is mine and is accurate to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magus cannot activate spells that require verbal components in silence, just like any caster.

He can still deliver touch spells he has prepared through his weapon with Spellstrike (level 2) if the spell was cast prior to the silence, as this does not dispel it, but he cannot activate a new spell (with Spell Combat) to deliver this way unless it was prepared with the Metamagic Silent Spell.